# Playing an image sequence in WPF at 120FPS

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I'm trying to create a program that takes an image sequence and plays it at the desired framerate (up to 120 FPS).

So far, I have a class that the Source of an Image control is bound to. This class stores a list of file locations and can recall the file location of the next frame. It looks like this:

```
public class VideoViewer : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string image;
    private List<string> imageLocs = new List<string>();
    private int imageIndex = 0;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string imageSource
    {
        get
        {
            return image;
        }
        set
        {
            image = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("imageSource");
        }
    }

    public List<string> imagesArray
    {
        get
        {
            return imageLocs;
        }
        set
        {
            imageLocs = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("imagesArray");
        }
    }

    public void NextFrame()
    {
        //If not on last frame
        if(imageIndex < (imageLocs.Count - 1))
        {
            //Add one to the index to select the next frame in the array
            imageIndex += 1;
            imageSource = imagesArray[imageIndex];

            //Update the image
            OnPropertyChanged("imageSource");
        }
        //If on the last frame of the array, reset to 0
        else if(imageIndex == (imageLocs.Count - 1))
        {
            imageIndex = 0;
            imageSource = imagesArray[imageIndex];
            OnPropertyChanged("imageSource");
        }
    }

    // Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

In my MainWindow I have 3 buttons, a browse button which loads the class, a play button that starts a DispatcherTimer which calls the NextFrame() method of my class every 1/120 seconds, and a stop button that stops the timer.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
    VideoViewer vV = new VideoViewer();
    DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = vV;
    }

    private void PlayButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1/120) };
        timer.Tick += TimerTick;
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void PauseButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Stop();
    }

    private void TimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        vV.NextFrame();
    }

    private void BrowseButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Set the file dialog to filter for graphics files.
        this.openFileDialog1.Filter =
            "Images (*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF;*.PNG)|*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF;*.PNG|" +
            "All files (*.*)|*.*";

        // Allow the user to select multiple images.
        this.openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;
        this.openFileDialog1.Title = "My Image Browser";

        DialogResult dr = this.openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (dr == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if (dr == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                List<string> images = new List<string>();

                // Read the files
                foreach (String file in openFileDialog1.FileNames)
                {
                    images.Add(file);
                }

                vV.imagesArray = images;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine at lower framerates, but does not seem to play the video any faster than 30 FPS (for example i would expect a 30 FPS video to play at 4x speed when set to 120 FPS)

Is there something other than a DispatcherTimer I can use to achieve the desired effect?

Comment: I guess loading your image from file and decoding it takes longer than your desired frame length.

Comment: How does it work fine? `1 / 120` will return `0` because of `int` calculations involved. This should be changed to something like `1D / 120D`. [Proof here](http://rextester.com/SJAT47106)

Comment: Changing from 1/120 to 1D/120D didn't do anything, it still plays at the same speed. And yeah, I was thinking if not a timer limitation it could just be taking too long to load the file.

Comment: You can verify that assumption by loading all images beforehand yourself (so your imagesArray will be of type `List<ImageSource>`).

Comment: Have you tried extending `UIElement` or `FrameworkElement` and using `OnRender` method to draw your images? This should be a lot faster than it is now.

Comment: I changed my list to an ImageSource, and seems it takes one loop of the frames to 'buffer', and then it plays at the desired speed, so thanks for that. Only problem now is it's starting to eat up memory and stops loading images at 2GB of process memory used.

Answer (score 1):

The Interval property of the DispatcherTimer is unfortunately not precise enough.

1. It will never fire off the "Tick" event any earlier than when the specified Interval is up, but...
2. It is very likely that it will take 15-25ms longer than the interval because there is still other stuff to finish.

It might improve slightly if you use...

```
DispatcherTimer dt = new DispatcherTimer(DispatcherPriority.Send);
```

...to increase the priority level but nowhere near 120FPS (8.3ms interval).

Maybe this helps a little:
Instead of subscribing to the "Tick" event of a DispatcherTimer you can subscribe to...

```
System.Windows.Media.CompositionTarget.Rendering += DoSomething;
```

...and at least get the events fired at a pretty reliable 60FPS on a modern PC.